# streams not working after upgrading to nodejs 10

Tags: node.js, fs

I have the following code that downloads a file from an ftp server.  The ftp package creates a read stream and I pipe that into a write stream.

```
ftp.connect(ftpConnObj)
    .then(function (data) {
        logging.log('Connected to FTP', clientId, jobId);
        return ftp.get('files/student.txt');
    }).then(function (stream) {
        logging.log('Downloading student file', clientId, jobId);
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            /*stream.once('close', function() {
                console.log("close event called");
                resolve();
            });*/
            stream.on('readable', function() {
                console.log('readable');
            });
            stream.on('data', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
            stream.on('end', function() {
                console.log('end');
            });
            stream.on('close', function() {
                console.log('close');
            });
            stream.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
            var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(dir + '/student.txt');
            stream.pipe(writeStream);
            writeStream.on('close', function() {
                console.log('closed');
                resolve();
            });
        });
```

This code works fine when using node 8.15.1.  When I upgraded to node 10.15.3 it no longer works.  The readable event on the read stream will get hit once but after that none of the other events get called so the code just hangs.

Is there something that changed in node 10 that requires this to be done differently?